# Is there an easy way to log all activity that a shell script does?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, programming

Is there an easy way to log all activity that occurs from a shell script to a file?

I have a script.  It outputs things like echo "instructions", as well as other program output. I know the commands:

```
command | tee -a "$log_file"
```

and

```
command >> logifle.log
```

What I'm asking is whether there is a shell parameter for logging, or a set command I can use or something like that. I don't necessarily want to add dozens of redirects or tee to files if I don't have to. I still want to get std output though - I just also want it to be logged.:wq

Comment: LOL, :wq like I were in vim'

Comment: it boggles my mind that most people seem to do that instead of :x

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you normally run your script with `foo.sh`, try running it (assuming it's a bash script) with `bash -x foo.sh`. If you want everything redirected to file, try `bash -x foo.sh > file.log 2>&1` (note I'm redirecting stderr as well, remove the `2>&1` if you don't want this). If you also want to see what's going on, `bash -x foo.sh 2>&1 | tee file.log`.

Answer (score 20):

There is a very easy and handy way:

Using `script` to make typescript of terminal session

1. Start the command `script`

   If the argument `file` is given, eg `script ~/tmp/output`, `script` saves the dialogue in this file. If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in the file `typescript`
2. Start your script or what ever you want to start
3. If your script is finished, stop `script` via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>
4. Check the output in the default output file `typescript`

---

To start your command in one step with `script`, use the parameter `-c`

```
-c COMMAND
    Run the COMMAND rather than an interactive 
    shell. This makes it easy for a script to capture
    the output of a program that behaves differently
    when its stdout is not a tty.
```

---

The usage of `script`inside your script makes no sense because `script` forks the shell or starts a new shell.

> If the variable SHELL exists, the shell forked by script will be that shell. If SHELL is not set, the Bourne shell is assumed. (Most shells set this variable automatically).

Comment: @Fabby I like my answer, but I don't see the little gray thing ;)

Comment: I use `script logfilename`, so I get to pick it.

Comment: can I call "script" from my shell program?

Comment: This makes no sense, see my improved answer.

Comment: I would like to run the command from inside the script , I will look into script this evening.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this answer :-) `script` is useful also a monitoring via a fifo. From `man script`: "`-f, --flush` Flush output after each write. This  is  nice  for  telecooperation:  one  person  does `mkfifo  foo;  script  -f  foo`,  and another can supervise real-time what is being done using `cat foo`". It can also be used to monitor when a program is waiting for input or done for example by monitoring the timestamp of the fifo.