# ./configure output in terminal but also in file with 2>&1?

Tags: compiling, configure

For compiling source code, I would like to know how I can "copy" the terminal output so that stdout and stderr go where they are supposed to go, but also to gedit.

When I use `./configure 2>&1 gedit -` then all terminal output is send to gedit but no longer where it needs to go internally. Is that correct?

Maybe I'm super wrong here but I couldn't manage to find clear instructions.

Thank you!
J

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to log all activity that a shell script does?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654706/is-there-an-easy-way-to-log-all-activity-that-a-shell-script-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man bash`, especially the "Redirection" section.

```
2>&1
```

redirects STDERR (the error stream) to the same place that STDOUT is going.

What do you mean "no longer where it needs to go internally"? The STDERR and STDOUT streams are produced by `./configure` as it goes about its business. How you process STDERR or STDOUT after the script outputs it generally won't affect the script (except `lots_of_output | read_a_byte_an_hour`).

What do you want `gedit` to process? Where is `gedit` going to write the edited file?

You could

```
./configure 2>/tmp/stderr >/tmp/stdout
```

then `gedit` either file.

If you want to save, STDERR along with STDOUT, and process it later, see `man tee`, and do:

```
./configure 2>&1 | tee /tmp/logfile | later_processing ...
```

Comment: I guess the `tee` command that copies a STDOUT to a file, but still displays it in the terminal, is what the OP searched for.