# How to save Output file

Tags: command-line

I am using SINGULAR (Math) software in terminal. Sometime terminal does not shows all output. 
Can i see/save all output?

**Example**
**INPUT**

```
ring r=0,(x(1..18)),dp;
ideal i=x(1)*x(2),x(2)*x(3),x(3)*x(4),x(4)*x(5),x(5)*x(6),x(6)*x(7),x(7)*x(8),x(8)*x(9),x(9)*x(1),x(1)*x(10),x(2)*x(11),x(3)*x(12),x(4)*x(13),x(5)*x(14),x(6)*x(15),x(7)*x(16),x(8)*x(17),x(9)*x(18);
LIB "primdec.lib";
```

**OUTPUT (Truncated)**

```
primdecGTZ(i);

      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[53]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[54]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[55]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(6)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(16)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(6)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[56]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(11)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(11)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[57]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[58]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(13)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[59]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
[60]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[61]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[62]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[63]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(15)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[64]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(6)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(10)
      _[4]=x(9)
      _[5]=x(8)
      _[6]=x(7)
      _[7]=x(6)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
[65]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(12)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[66]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[67]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[68]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(14)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[69]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(11)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[70]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[71]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(13)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[72]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(12)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(12)
      _[2]=x(10)
      _[3]=x(9)
      _[4]=x(8)
      _[5]=x(7)
      _[6]=x(6)
      _[7]=x(5)
      _[8]=x(4)
      _[9]=x(2)
[73]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(12)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(12)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
[74]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(11)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(11)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(1)
[75]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(10)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(10)
      _[2]=x(9)
      _[3]=x(8)
      _[4]=x(7)
      _[5]=x(6)
      _[6]=x(5)
      _[7]=x(4)
      _[8]=x(3)
      _[9]=x(2)
[76]:
   [1]:
      _[1]=x(9)
      _[2]=x(8)
      _[3]=x(7)
      _[4]=x(6)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
   [2]:
      _[1]=x(9)
      _[2]=x(8)
      _[3]=x(7)
      _[4]=x(6)
      _[5]=x(5)
      _[6]=x(4)
      _[7]=x(3)
      _[8]=x(2)
      _[9]=x(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which program are you using for terminal?

In Ubuntu default "Terminal" you can set the number of scrollback lines. Increase them to get all the output. Go to Edit->Profile preferences->Scrolling->Limit scrollback to.

I believe almost all terminal programs have an option to set the number of scroll lines you can see. If you are not using "Terminal" you need to find the preference in your favourite terminal.

Comment: Can i save the output?

Comment: @Selva Copy+Paste is always available :) But probably it is worth reading section 2.1.9 of Singular Manual, where it says how to write to files directly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/654711/367165